# Filter out text in uvscan

Tags: linux, centos7

I am trying to get a dat set version and compare it to output from a control file. My control file (for this line) reads: `Dat Set 10349`

The command I am using is

```
/usr/local/bin/uvscan --version | grep 'Dat set' | cut -d ' ' | -f1-4
```

The return I get is `Dat set version: 10349`
What I want is to remove "version: " so that the return matches my control line. I know very little about linux commands, so is this possible? Snd if so, how would I go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out immediately of course. I piped `sed s/'version: '//`
Full command is

```
/usr/local/bin/uvscan --version | grep 'Dat set' | cut -d ' ' | -f1-4 | sed s/'version: '//
```